# How to masking a credit card number in Nativescript Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, nativescript

I want to display credit card number as **1234****6789** format in my Nativescript Angular app.
My data source is an array. I am displaying list of credit card numbers in a Listview.

```
let creditCards = [
            {
                cardNo : 123456789,
                expiryDate: 25/12/2020,
            },
            {
                cardNo : 987654321,
                expiryDate: 25/12/2020,
            },

        ];
```

Html

```
<ListView [items]="creditCards">
     <ng-template let-item="item">
         <GridLayout rows="*,*" columns="*,*">
             <Label row="0" col=0 [text]="item.cardNo"></Label>
             <Label row="0" col=0 [text]="item.cardNo"></Label>
         </GridLayout>
      </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

I know, I can achieve this by replacing the **cardNo** string. But
What is the best way to masking the credit card number without modifying the actual data source.
Can this be done in html/css?

Comment: You could try taking your data source, taking the length and repeating the asterisks content for that many times. For example: `'*'.repeat(dataSource.length)` as the text binding. I am not sure how it'll initially look as you type (most validators show the last value key).

Answer (score 0):

It occurs to me that before displaying the array data, you pass the fix by a masked function and then show it in the list you need.

http://www.forosdelweb.com/f13/enmascarar-input-tarjeta-credito-954207/

Comment: the "angular way" is using a custom pipe https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes